# Angular | Give alias to 'Template Reference Variable' aka let-list

Tags: angular

I have a .ts file with a list like so:

```
list: any[] = [];
```

I'm iterating a list like so in the template:

```
<p-table [value]="list">
    <ng-template let-list>
     {{list.personID}}
    </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

Is there a way to give an alias to this 'list' ?

Pseudocode example:

```
<ng-template let-list as person>
{{person.personID}}
</ng-template>
```

The reason for this would be to improve code comprehension.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. We need the full context of your code to help you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using primeNG.

Have you read [the documentation](https://primeng.org/table#basic) ?

```html
<p-table [value]="list">
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-person>
        <tr>
            <td>{{ person.personID }}</td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
</p-table>
```